# Method for "removing" information from a field without losing the information that was contained there?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that essentially consists of updates to records pertaining to customers. For auditing purposes, we need to be able to reconstruct a narrative of the changes to a given field so the solution I came up with is to simply have users enter updates, and then the client information display form relies on a bunch of queries that determine what the most recent update that changed a given field was, and pull the value from that update.  So far this works fine.

The issue comes when I want to simply remove a value from the given field.  I tried recording a blank space character in the data entry form, expecting that would let the query detect it since " " is not the same thing as Null.  I was, apparently, mistaken.

I could pass a hyphen easily enough, but I'm wondering if there's a more obvious solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a change log or audit log. If it were me, I would create a function or sub-procedure I could call from anywhere I might add/update/delete. The parms include the field name you are changing, the 'before' value, the 'after' value, and any "key fields" that makes sense for you like a customer number or other id number that you foresee being needed for audit access purposes. The subprocedure itself will write the audit log record with the timestamp.  Then, IF there is an audit...you could pull that up for any date range and see the history of any field. Just one approach, and good luck.